# Why does nothing in WPF have a click event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, click

This seems very strange to me.

I know through some adventurous inheritance you can convert most UIElements to a button, but it is a cumbersome way of implementing the most basic of of computer events

Comment: You might get better help if you rephrased your question so we know *why* you want a Click event.  Most likely you just want MouseDown or MouseUp.

Comment: I'm not really looking for an answer to a specific question, I'm more wondering why microsoft would leave this out.

Comment: I agree with the question.  There is a very distinct difference between MouseDown/MouseUp and Click events.  In order to jump from the first raw events to the second (derived), a certain logic has to execute:  whether MouseUp corresponds to the previous MouseDown (over the same control, with the same mouse-button..).  It becomes even trickier when the need for DoubleClick arises.  IMHO this logic should be provided by the framework (i.e. WPF), instead of each of us be implementing our own home-grown mechanisms.  WinForms does!..  Is is so hard for WPF to do?

Answer (score 6):

The [`ButtonBase` class certainly has a `Click` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx). So has derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most basic events are MouseDown and MouseUp which are available to every UIElement

Answer (score 1):

use RoutedEvents event if you really need to use.
Other wise use dependency property to register a Click event  against your control and then do what ever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add RoutedEvents to your controls.

[Here](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Concepts%E2%80%94Routed_Event_Implementation) is an implementation example